# How to add add existing directory to version control in existing repo without modifying files?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-checkout

I have to put a pretty big project under version control, which has two versions (dev and prod). These two were kept in "mostly sync" by copying files manually over the years, but - obviously - they diverged from each other pretty heavily.

The dev version is already in git, and now I need to put the production version under version control, too, but *without modifying any existing files to avoid loss of code*. My plan is to first gitignore all files in the production directory and as I work on them to remove any differences manually, I slowly add them back until all files are added and I can just normally `git pull` to get any code changes.

The method I tried is*:

1. go to production directory
2. `git init`
3. `git fetch --all`
4. `git checkout origin:release -- .gitignore` to get normal gitignore file
5. add the line `**/*` to .gitignore
6. `git checkout release`

If I don't check out the existing gitignore and just use a clean .gitignore with `**/*` as the only line, git still updates the files.

I thought that because of the newly added line in `.gitignore` my working directory would survive the checkout unharmed, but I was wrong.

Is there a way to fetch everything and go to the release branch *without changing my working directory*?

* I used a copy of the production directory to avoid accidentally destroying anything

Comment: Why don't you simply create a different branch under same `dev` repository (called `prod` or `main` or `master` which is "old" nomenclature)? This way you can push all current `prod` status. Then, when you're ready to reconcile (I'll suggest sooner than later) you can just merge `dev` into `prod` (or better, the first time, you'll merge `prod` into `dev`, then all other changes should go in `dev` and then merged in `prod`).

Answer (score 0):

> The dev version is already in git, and now I need to put the production version under version control, too,

So:

```
cd /path/to/dev/repository
git switch -c prod dev
git --work-tree=/path/to/current/prod add .
git status
```

That way, you can quickly see what is modified (added/removed) by the prod file in a working tree initialized from dev.